# How to make custom filter wait while items are undefined and loading asynchronously?

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

I have a custom filter working in an ng-repeat.  The items in the ng-repeat come from a BaaS called firebase.

I'm trying to make a way for a user to filter events by date (in 3 days, in 7 days, etc).  I wrote a custom filter for this and it works with dummy data [here](http://codepen.io/kpennell/pen/jFasi).

Now I'm trying to do it via my dummy events data coming in via $asArray (this comes from firebase).

I get the error ""Error: items is undefined".  As I understand it, this is because the filter and ng-repeat are trying to call on the data before it has loaded.

I'm guessing I need some logic in my filter that says if `items === undefined`, wait until it loads.  I don't know how to write the logic to do this.  I've tried $timeout but could not get it to work.

Here's the filter part:

```
.filter('upComing', function() {

//    if (items === undefined){    
//     WAIT UNTIL it loads!

      return function(items, field, days){
         var timeStart = Date.now();
         var timeEnd = Date.now() + (days * 86400000); // 1 day in ms
      return items.filter(function(item){
         return (item[field] > timeStart && item[field] < timeEnd);
      });
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oJtQjv7pRCXoTD6ecK0e?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write the filter in such as a way that it caters for the first parameter being undefined.

e.g.

```
.filter('upComing', function() {
      return function(items, field, days){
         var timeStart = Date.now();
         var timeEnd = Date.now() + (days * 86400000); // 1 day in ms
      return (items || []).filter(function(item){
         return (item[field] > timeStart && item[field] < timeEnd);
      });
```

Angular is going to call your filter on *every digest*, which includes when the page first loads, before the data has been loaded from the database asynchronously. So all of your code needs to work correctly if the data has not been loaded in first. `|| <default value>` and `if (!param) return;` are your friends here.

Comment: This helped but I'm not totally solved yet.  If the array isn't there yet, won't the `|| []` just return a blank array then?  That seems to be what's happening now.  Not getting the error but not getting the data either.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the `|| []` will return a blank array from this filter. However, because filters get called whenever the input changes, it will get re-evaluated when your data is loaded in. The real reason your filter didn't work is because it had a few bugs in it. I have [forked your Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dU2rBfw5HKsl2PVQlmDl?p=preview) and fixed it so it shows up data when you click one of the links.

Comment: Mister Australia @GregL, you absolutely made my night.  I would not have figured that out on my own.  I'll need to go read up on what `parse` does now.  I can't tell you how much I appreciate this.

Comment: Glad I could help. [`$parse`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) is what Angular uses to convert expressions into functions that can be evaluated against a particular scope. P.S. Don't forget to accept my answer.